# GTM preview not starting

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a GTM installed on the site. GTM tracking code is present on the site, and Google Tag Assistant (Chrome extension) shows that it fires.
But when I press Preview and open the site, I don't see the usual GTM panel on the bottom with information which tag fired and which didn't.

Can it be because of a Javascript error on the site?

> custom.js?5b6084:316 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'totalPanels' of undefined

If not, what can it be?

Comment: This looks like an error message from a Chrome extension (judging by "totalPanels" this is an extension that tries to add to the developer tools), so you might want to check if you have extensions installed and disable them for testing. However I have occasionally the same problem with GTM and in the past it helped to delete all cookies and restart the browser.

Answer (score 2):

GTM Preview is cookie based. It won't work if you suppress cookies, or if you have the site open in one instance of chrome and GTM open in another (so if one of them is open in an incognito tab, or if you have two seperate Chrome profiles running at once).
I'd check your cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure no script or ad blocking browser add-ons are running (e.g., uBlock Origin, AdBlock, Adblock Plus etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Later noticed that GTM Debugger wont preview if you are logged in as admin in the CMS.